# Powershell class method return being cast to new type

Tags: powershell, class, casting, return-value

I am working on a new PowerShell class that takes the path to an XML file in my old format and converts it to my new format. The constructor takes the path argument and calls a method, which should return a custom object with either the XML or an error message explaining the absence of the XML. What is odd is that the XML portion of the custom object is XML before the method returns, but immediately after it has been cast to a string.

So this class

```
class pxT_DefinitionsMigrater {
    # Properties
    $XML = [xml.xmlDocument]::New()
    $Errors = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

    # Constructor
    pxT_DefinitionsMigrater ([string]$xmlPath) {
        if ($oldDefinition = $this.readXMLFile($xmlPath).xml) {
            $this.XML = $oldDefinition.xml
            Write-Host "pxT_DefinitionsMigrater: $($oldDefinition.xml.GetType().FullName)"
        } else {
            $this.Errors = $oldDefinition.error
        }
    }

    # Methods
    [psCustomObject] readXMLFile ([string]$xmlPath) { 
        $readXMLFile = [psCustomObject]@{    
            xml   = $null
            error = $null
        }
        
        $fileStream = $null
        $xmlreader = $null
        $importFile = [xml.xmlDocument]::New()
        $xmlReaderSettings = [xml.xmlReaderSettings]::New()
        $xmlReaderSettings.closeInput = $true
        $xmlReaderSettings.prohibitDtd = $false
        
        try {
            $fileStream = [io.fileStream]::New($xmlPath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
            $xmlreader = [xml.xmlreader]::Create($fileStream, $xmlReaderSettings)
            $importFile.Load($xmlreader)
        } catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
            if ($_.Exception.Message -match ': "(?<string>.*)"$') {
                $readXMLFile.error = "Error loading XML; $($matches['string'])" # removes 'Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s):' from message
            } else {
                $readXMLFile.error = "Error loading XML; $($_.Exception.Message)"
            }
        } catch {
            $readXMLFile.error = "Error loading XML; $($_.Exception.FullName) - $($_.Exception.Message)"
        } finally {
            if ($xmlreader) {
                $xmlreader.Dispose()
            }
            if ($readXMLFile.error) {
                $readXMLFile.xml = $null
            } else {
                $readXMLFile.xml = $importFile
            }
        }
        Write-Host "readXMLFile: $($readXMLFile.xml.GetType().FullName)"
        return $readXMLFile
    }
    
}
```

Will echo

```
readXMLFile: System.Xml.XmlDocument 
pxT_DefinitionsMigrater: System.String
```

I am contemplating moving the XML load code into the ctor since that is the only place it is needed, but the fact that the XML is getting cast to string seems like something I need to understand. What is causing this? And what do I need to do to make this work with the method, should I want to?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue - I get a "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." exception instead. I think there's something funky with your constructor logic though - you're assigning ```$oldDefinition = $this.readXMLFile($xmlPath).xml``` in the ```if```, but then you're accessing ```$oldDefinition.xml``` (i.e. the ```xml``` property again) on the next line. I think you might want to capture the result of ```$this.readXMLFile($xmlPath)``` into a temporary variable and then access the ```xml``` and ```error``` properties of that as appropriate.

Comment: @mclayton Indeed, `$this.XML = $oldDefinition.xml` is a byproduct of me trying to test where things where going south. `$oldDefinition` is intended to be the temporary variable, then I'll do the translation in another temporary variable, while also logging an issues in a temporary error variable. 
FWIW, I moved all the XML read code out of the method and into the constructor, and everything works fine. Weird that returning something from the method would change the type.

Comment: Cool. sounds like you've got a workable fix. I also noticed that you're using ```$oldDefinition.xml``` in the ```write-host``` as well. I think your code should maybe have been ```$oldDefinition = $this.readXMLFile($xmlPath); if( $oldDefinition.xml ) ...``` so you could refer to ```$oldDefinition.xml``` and ```$oldDefinition.error``` elsewhere in the constructor.

Comment: @mclayton, it's a workable fix, but it sure would be nice to know why the XML is getting cast to string. I can see needing to return complex data from a method, and this would break that functionality.